# Create every possible string combination by the abc

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create something that will generate every possible combination for a word until 4 chars.

for example will start as a,b,c...aa,ab,ac...aaa,aab,aac...aaaa,aaab,aaac....zzzx,zzzy,zzzz

closest thing that i cam close to, was this:

```
import itertools
for i in range(4):
    for combination in itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-([{0123456789', i):
        word = str(combination).replace("'", '').replace("(", '').replace(")", '').replace(" ", '').replace(",", '')
        print(word)
```

the problem with this, is that it does not create combinations with same characters, like aa,bb,cc.

Comment: Same exactly code - replace ```combinations``` with ```combinations_with_replacement```: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

Comment: Just noticed. it does not provide everything. as you can see, there is no (b,a,a) for example.

Comment: You should go with ```itertools.product``` then - ```combinations``` implies irrelevant order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order is meaningful- `itertools.product` is the way to go:

```py
import itertools
for i in range(4):
    for combination in itertools.product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-([{0123456789', repeat=i):
        word = ''.join(combination)
        print(word)
```

Comment: Actually order was not really important, that this is exactly what I need! thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked :) I also tweaked the piece for creating ```word``` (the one you had these multiple ```replace``` for)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `combinations_with_replacement` instead of  `combinations`.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list(combinations_with_replacement('abc', 3))
[('a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'b'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c', 'c'),
 ('b', 'b', 'b'),
 ('b', 'b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c', 'c'),
 ('c', 'c', 'c')]
```

Comment: Just noticed.
it does not provide everything.
as you can see, there is no (b,a,a) for example.